# Prove that $v_1^{T}v_2 = [0] $ (the 1 by 1 zero matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra

This question is from a Linear Algebra past exam paper that I am reviewing as I study for finals. The full question is:

> Suppose that $M$ is a square matrix. Recall that $M^T$ denotes the transpose of $M$, the result of interchanging columns and rows of $M$. Recall that
>   $$ (AB)^{T} = B^TA^T$$
>   for any square matrices $A$ and $B$ of the same size. (You do not need to prove this and may quote it freely).
>
> Suppose that the remainder of this problem $M=M^T$ (we call this a symmetric matrix).
>
> (i) Prove that if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are eigenvectors of $M$ with respect to eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ such that $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$  then $v_1^{T}v_2 = [0] = 0 $ (the 1 by 1 matrix with entry zero).

The solution is given as follows:

> We have that $Mv_1 = \lambda_1v_1$ and $Mv_2 = \lambda_2v_2$. 
>   $$
> v_1^{T}v_2 = (\frac{1}{\lambda_1}\lambda_1 v_1)^Tv_2 = \frac{1}{\lambda_1}(Mv_1)^Tv_2 =  \frac{1}{\lambda_1} v_1^TM^Tv_2 = \frac{1}{\lambda_1}v_1^TMv_2 = \frac{1}{\lambda_1}v_1^T\lambda_2v_2 = \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}v_1^Tv_2
> $$
>   so that $v_1^{T}v_2 - \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}v_1^Tv_2 = 0$. Then $(1 - \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})v_1^Tv_2=0$ and since $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$, then $ v_1^Tv_2 = 0$.

What I am struggling to understand about this solution is how $ (AB)^{T} = B^TA^T$
can be applied to $(Mv_1)^T$, when it is clearly stated that this holds when $A$ and $B$ are square matrices of the same size? Could someone enlighten me?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, it holds for all matrices where $AB$ is well-dimensioned. Looks like a slip-up.

Comment: Be careful. Eigenvalues can be zero.

Comment: Wow that was easy - one quick search of wikipedia confirms it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I disagree with your teacher:

You should at least once prove for yourself, that for *any* matrices $A,B$ such that $\exists AB$, we do have
$$(AB)^T=B^TA^T\,.$$

Comment: Will do. Many thanks.

Comment: It's easy from the row-column rule of matrix multiplication.